# What happens to the molecules during Latent heat phase?

Tags: thermodynamics

From my current current understanding of evaporation and boiling - when we put a beaker filled with water under the sun we observe evaporation. Evaporation is a surface phenomenon. Surface molecules are only held by cohesive forces from one side thus the potential energy binding them from escaping is lesser than that would be for the bulk molecules (not surface molecules.) So thus we observe that even at lower temperatures, when the average kinetic energy is lesser these surface molecules are lost, after which the layer underneath it becomes the surface layer and so on till we have an empty beaker. Meanwhile boiling occurs when we have given a good amount of heat enough that the kinetic energy can liberate all molecules, enough that even the bulk molecules are ready to leave.

I do not seem to understand why exactly during this transition from evaporation to boiling do we observe a latent heat. From my understanding, upon heating an object it has collisions with other particles of higher kinetic energy increasing it's kinetic energy, but during the latent heat phase we observe no change in kinetic energy. What exactly occurs during this latent heat phase? Why don't these molecules just keep on increasing their kinetic energy from these collisions and go to the gaseous phase?